# Cache Custom Class with NSCache

Tags: ios, swift, caching, memory

I am trying to Cache my custom class so I can reload it when user is offline. I am new to Swift so I have been looking around and most people said use NSCache. I have used this method in my class but It doest work.

```
let cache = NSCache<NSString, ShopProfileModel>()
let myObject: ShopProfileModel

if let cachedVersion = cache.object(forKey: "CachedObject") {
    // use the cached version
    myObject = cachedVersion
    print("Object has been cached")
} else {
    // create it from scratch then store in the cache
    myObject = self.shopProfileModel
    cache.setObject(myObject, forKey: "CachedObject")
    print("Object has not been cached")
}
```

It always prints "Object has not been cached". Any idea why my object is not cached?

Comment: Is myObject nil?

Comment: @TusharSharma I just checked and its not nil

Comment: where you created object of ShopProfileModel? You doing setObject and saving a type i guess.I mean try myObject=ShopProfileModel(), and save this object.